# How to convert char to integer from .txt file in C++

Tags: c++

I have a .txt file that contains:

```
XXXX:YYYY:ABCCCCE.
```

I need to write a function that reads this section of the .txt file `ABCCCCE` and finds the sum of the values of those characters.

Assume:

```
A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 5
```

Here is what I have so far to distinguish the values of each character:

```
int getComplexity(char theCode)
{
int complexity;

if(theCode == 'A')
{
    complexity = 1;
} else if(theCode == 'B')
{
    complexity = 2;
} else if(theCode == 'C')
{
    complexity = 3;
} else if(theCode == 'D')
{
    complexity = 4;
} else if(theCode == 'E')
{
    complexity = 5;
}

return complexity;
}
```

I'm just not sure how I would read from the .txt file and convert the values. I am new to c++ so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Lala5th -- C++ does not require that the character codes for letters be contiguous and increasing, so there is no guarantee that `theCode - 'A' + 1` will do anything sensible. Digits are required to be contiguous and increasing, so `digitCode - '0'` works correctly. There are character codes (EBCDIC, for one) which have gaps within the codes for letters.

Comment: use maps, it will make it more simple or use switches.

Comment: found a solution. Testing it to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what your after but:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int Return_Complexity(char character)
{
    switch (character)
    {
    case 'a':
        return 1;
        break;
    case 'b':
        return 2;
        break;
    case 'c':
        return 3;
        break;
    case 'd':
        return 4;
        break;
    case 'e':
        return 5;
        break;
    default:
        return 0; //Zero indicates that we didn't find what we're looking for
    }
}
int main()
{
    ifstream file{ "some-file.txt" };
    vector<int> values;
    char character;
    while (file >> character)
    {
        int result = Return_Complexity(tolower(character));
        if (result > 0) //if its a-e
            values.push_back(result);
    }
    int Result = accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 1); //add them together
    cout << Result;
}
```

this pushes back all characters found and then sums them up.

If this is not what your after, i will fix this.